# How to redirect page using Route?

Tags: react-router

I kinda wanna do a function that when i click on every item in the navbar and even the submenu in each item, it will rediret me to a new page with relevant information, i thought of using **Route** inside my Link tag but i kinda stuck in how to do that. Should i use Route or other codes to achive this task? I'd like to hear recommendations from you guys, thank you btw!

Navbar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { navItems } from "./NavItems";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./Navbar.css";
import DropDown from "./DropDown";

function Navbar() {
  const [dropDown, setDropdown] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="nav-items">
        {navItems.map((item) => {
          if (item.title === "Services") {
            return (
              <li
                onClick={() => setDropdown(!dropDown)}
                key={item.id}
                className={item.cName}
                onMouseEnter={() => setDropdown(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setDropdown(false)}
              >
                <Router>
                  <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
                </Router>
                {dropDown && <DropDown />}
              </li>
            );
          }
          return (
            <Router>
              <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            </Router>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Navbar;
```

DropDown.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { serviceDropdown } from "./NavItems";
import { Link, BrowserRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import "./DropDown.css";

function DropDown() {
  return (
    <div>
      <ul className="subnav-items">
        {serviceDropdown.map((item) => {
          return (
            <Router>
              <li key={item.id} className={item.cName}>
                <Link to={item.path}>{item.title}</Link>
              </li>
            </Router>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DropDown;
```

Sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dropdown-menu-ho4h8?file=/src/components/DropDown.js:0-560

Comment: You are rendering too many routers, you need only one near the root of your app to provide a routing context for all the links and routes. I don't exactly understand your question. The links in your codesandbox appear all update the URL, but you aren't rendering any routes at all. Is this the question/issue, where to render the routes?

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to use the `useHistory` hook from react-router and use the `push` method to move to a different page. The code would look as follows

```js
const history = useHistory();

// Use the onClick props of your dropdown element

onClick={() => history.push("other URL");}
```